# Error Debug "0" como lo resuelvo?

Tags: depuración

> org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule.begin [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'debug' to '0' did not find a matching property

Este es el mensaje principal y el único error que me arroja el `LOG` al momento de iniciar el servidor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chequeá el archivo `/etc/tomcat7/context.xml` de tomcat. Si te figura el tag `<Context debug="1" ...>` probá comentandolo o eliminandolo.

Comment: Gracias de mucha ayuda. 

aunque no encontré el debug="1" en context lo encontré en Server.xml de igual manera funciono comentarlo

Comment: Excelente. @AngeloMazzey si te fue de ayuda no olvides de marcar la respuesta como aceptada.